# How to select json objects in android based on value

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I have the following code.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A blue door",
    "price": 10.50,
    "tags": ["home", "blue"]
}
```

I Want to be able to select only the objects that have an certain "id".

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    String name = json.opString("name");
    String price = json.optString("price");
    String tags = json.optString("tags");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JSON data is more along the lines of

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "A green door",
            "price": 12.5,
            "tags": [
                "home",
                "green"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "A blue door",
            "price": 10.5,
            "tags": [
                "home",
                "blue"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use jsonPath to get, for example, only id == 2

`$.objects[?(@.id=='2')]`

Comment: For the uninformed, you can download jsonPath here. [https://code.google.com/p/json-path/](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/)

Comment: @WaffleStealer654 Thanks! I was just looking for the link.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONObject` does not include anything to query the objects. You have to loop through all the elements yourself and compare the `id`.